# keras evaulate method results vary with equal testset

Tags: keras, training

I trained [segnet](https://github.com/ZFTurbo/ZF_UNET_224_Pretrained_Model/blob/master/zf_unet_224_model.py) on a dataset of remote sensing imagery. When I run `model.evaluate` a set of metrics is returned. When I compile the model again with the same settings and evaulate the model again, the results differ. For as far as I understand, there is nothing stochastic or random in the compiling of the model, am I right? I thought that the order of the training images in the batches could make a difference, so I tried a batch size of 1, but still I get different results.

Does the initialization of the model result in different results when predicting as well? And if yes, how do I resolve this?

This is the code I'm using for the initialization of the network:

```
def my_acc(y_true, y_pred):
    class_id_true = K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1)
    class_id_preds = K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
    accuracy_mask = K.cast(K.equal(class_id_preds, 1), 'int32')
    class_acc_tensor = K.cast(K.equal(class_id_true, class_id_preds), 'int32') * accuracy_mask
    class_acc = K.sum(class_acc_tensor) / K.maximum(K.sum(accuracy_mask), 1) 
    return class_acc

model = ZF_UNET_224() # This model is from the link in the beginning of the text
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0000001), 
              loss = class_weighted_pixelwise_crossentropy,
              metrics=['accuracy',my_acc,'categorical_accuracy'])
model.evaluate(x=imgs_test,y=imgs_mask_test,batch_size = 1,verbose=1)



# result1: [77778.927522078811, 0.94418407911839697, 0.0039057209515957264, 0.94418407911839697]
# result2: [77586.558084239135, 0.077934800141045577, 0.02123359974321911,  0.077934800141045577]
```